# Can't add functionalities to my UIPageViewController's UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I've made a UIPageViewController, which will administrate 3 UIViewControllers.

It all seems to work just fine, right until I add a button in the storyboard, and hook it up with a IBOutlet - then my app crashes with:

> "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Also, if I hook the button up with an IBAction, the app crashes when tapping the button.

```
class PostPageViewController: UIPageViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("IN PAGE VC!!")

        self.dataSource = self

        if let firstViewController = orderedViewControllers.first {
            print("IN FIRST!! \(firstViewController)")
            setViewControllers([firstViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    private(set) lazy var orderedViewControllers: [UIViewController] = {
        return [self.newViewController("1"), self.newViewController("2"), self.newViewController("3")]
    }()

    private func newViewController(number: String) -> UIViewController {
        return self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewPostVC\(number)")
    }
}
```

I have an extension controlling the pages as well, but I don't think that's interesting in this situation.

Here's my first view controller, thats causing the problem:

```
class NewPostVC1: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var cancelButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func cancelButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        print("Cancel button tapped!")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("NEWPOSTVC 111111")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

So, as said, the app creashed when tapping the button - I guess it's something about the UIPageViewController not being able to figure out which UIViewController is interacting, but I haven't been able to find anything that confirms this. Does anyone have an idea about this issue?

**UPDATE**: I just figured out that mu first viewController isnt instanciated, but number 2 and 3 are.. So right now my issue is that I have to load my viewcontroller somehow, before its shown - OR simply just dont have any functionality on the first page, and only on number 2 and 3.. Does anyone have a suggestion for instanciate the first viewcontroller before its shown? I've tried storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewPostVC1"), but it doesn't do the job!

Comment: You need to provide more details. What's the complete error? Which line of code causes the error?

Comment: The line that causes the error isnt shown. It just crashes - but I've debugged on my own, and found out that as soon I create a IBOutlet for my button, it doesn't work anymore.. Thats why I cant figure out whats going wrong

Answer (score 1):

Those kinds of error usually mean you have hooked something up incorrectly on the storyboard. E.g. you've added an IBAction, hooked it up to the button action but then gone back to the code and changed the name of the method (by accident or on purpose).

Comment: Yea, but I've checked it all - as I mention in the comment above your answer, the crash happens as soon as I hook up the viewcontroller with a IBOutlet to my button.. Nothing else is hooked up

Comment: I guess it's because my viewcontroller isnt connected to the the rest of my app, as its my pageview controller that connects it in code.. I mean - theres no arrows between them in the storyboard